# Tanach with grammatical text analysis

Tags: product-recommendation, tanach

Is there a tanach which analyses each word of the text that one should not need to look up the dikduk in the concordance every time. I believe there is a non-Jewish one.

Comment: If the analysis that you're looking for is strictly grammatical, what difference does the publisher's religion make??

Comment: It doesnt but I would still prefer a Jewish one if it exists which I think it ought to. One should be learning chumash analysing each word.

Comment: What about the classical commentators? Between all of them they usually do a pretty exhaustive job. Try looking and the [Torat Chaim Chumash](https://www.mosadharavkook.com/shop/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94-%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%99-%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94/) put out by Mossad Harav Kook. Rav Hirsch's commentary may not be as extensive as you are looking for but it may be close

Comment: @Jewels I am not looking for a commentary. Before one does that one has to know correct translation. That can only be acquired by using what has been given in the answer.

Comment: [picture of page](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fhbKk.png) This is how the page should look like to be able to translate. once one knows the root one can always also check it in the concordance.

Comment: Many of the early commentators, and Rav Hirsch as well, perhaps even more that the others, devote much of their commentaries to ascertaining the meaning and definitions of the individual words before proceeding to comment on their interpretation of the verses. Among the early commentators the two that particularly stand out in my mind in this regard are the Ibn Ezra and Saadya Gaon

Comment: Additionally, if you are looking to approach bible study from an Orthodox perspective, you stand to possibly loose by using non-Jewish sources. They will likely evaluate the meanings of words not only based on the biblical usage but based on the phonetic relation of the word with words in other ancient Semitic languages. Often these interpretations are given precedence over purely biblical contextual evaluation which leads to being forced to reinterpret passages in the bible as a result

Comment: @Jewels Reading the forward of the book mentioned (on line) he claims to use the Jewish Mandelkorn concordance. I am not a great fan of learning rishonim and certainly not R Hirsch before one can translate correctly. The 'meaning and definition' of words are best done simply by using the root and the grammar rules. I myself have already written in my own chumash the grammar of every word using the help of the concordance and I believe everyone should be doing the same.

Comment: Using root and grammar rules are exactly what these commentaries are all about, so I'm not sure what you are against. R Hirsch's primary goal, as he says in his introduction, is to ascertain the meaning of the text by studying the roots of the words exclusively within the biblical context. If there are other texts that do the same, great! But I don't understand which part of that aspect of the prashanut of Rav Hirsch and the rishonim you are against. Again, I'm not referring to their exegesis, just the part that is about definition of words

Comment: @Jewels One doesnt use a sledgehammer to crack a nut and doesnt run before one can walk. The book I quoted does things simply. I specially made a copy of it to show how simple it is.

Comment: I should mention the pri megodim says you should use such a type of chumash called chumash 'chilulim' which is available on hebrew books and know the root and grammar of every word

Comment: could you please post a reference to the Pri Megadim and a link to the chumash?

Comment: http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42651&st=&pgnum=146&hilite= The pri megadim is in his letters I havent time now to post the link. The idea is that the roots are in a different font and when missing above the word

Answer (score 3):

The only texts with which I'm familiar that do anything like this are Davidson's [*The Analytical Hebrew and Chaldee Lexicon*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0913573035) and the [*Old Testament Parsing Guide*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805420320), by Beall, Smith and Banks. The first is structured more like a dictionary, while the second follows the verses in their literary order (as it is maintained in the Christian tradition - ie: concluding with Malachi). I know of no other text like it.

I should add that using any text of this nature can be risky. Grammatical analysis is hardly an "exact science", and there's a great deal of scope for varied opinion when it comes to parsing words. The best thing is always to consult lexicons, grammars and concordances, and to pay careful attention to mefarshim like Ibn Ezra and Radak. I don't think there's a shortcut, and even if there were it would just be one person's (or one committee's) opinion. But if you're learning to parse, a parsing guide like the one I mentioned can be a useful supplement, and is not influenced by the authors' theology.

Comment: Thank you that is the kind of book I am looking for. I dont think that there can be anything wrong just because it is not from a Jewish source which I would have preferred. And that is really the only way to learn chumash and translate it correctly

Comment: http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42651&st=&pgnum=146&hilite= is another text